# Laguerre Polynomial Series

Tags: functional-analysis, special-functions

I am trying to find sum of this series,

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\gamma} \binom{\gamma}{k} L_n^{a + k}(x) L_{c + k}^{b - k}(x).$$

Ideas/clues are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

can you use this $\sum_{k=0}^{\gamma} \binom{\gamma}{k}L_{m + k}^{\alpha - k}(x) = L_{m+\gamma}^{\alpha}(x)$ and $\sum_{k=0}^{\gamma}L_k^{\alpha}(x) = L_{\gamma}^{\alpha+1}(x) $ ??

Comment: Well.  There is another Laguerre polynomial within the sum. If I expand the later, then these relations do not apply.